# How to disable command output in jenkins pipeline build logs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkinsfile for scripting of a pipeline.

Is there any way to disable printing of executed shell commands in build logs?

Here is just a simple example of a jenkins pipeline:

```
node{
  stage ("Example") {
    sh('echo shellscript.sh arg1 arg2')
    sh('echo shellscript.sh arg3 arg4')        
  }
}
```

which produces the following output in console log:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testpipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] sh
[testpipeline] Running shell script
+ echo shellscript.sh arg1 arg2  
shellscript.sh arg1 arg2
[Pipeline] sh
[testpipeline] Running shell script
+ echo shellscript.sh arg3 arg4
shellscript.sh arg3 arg4
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Basically I would like to disable printing of the commands itself.

```
+ echo shellscript.sh arg1 arg2
+ echo shellscript.sh arg3 arg4
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

By default Jenkins starts shell scripts with flags `-xe`. `-x` enables additional logging. `-e` makes the script exit if any command inside returns non-zero exit status. To reset a flag I'd suggest two options:

1. Call `set +x` in the body of your script.

   ```
   sh 'set +x'
   ```
2. Pass custom shebang line without `-x`:

   ```
   sh('#!/bin/sh -e\n' + 'echo shellscript.sh arg1 arg2')
   ```

As for the second option you can define a wrapper function for convenience which will prepend the script with custom shebang and then call `sh`

```
def mysh(cmd) {
    sh('#!/bin/sh -e\n' + cmd)
}
```

Comment: This is for anyone who is working for windows => 

output = bat(returnStdout: true, script: '<SOME_COMMAND>')

Comment: The 'alias' list was being printed for every sh in a pipeline script.  I didn't figure out where/how 'alias' was called for every sh command.  But using just '-e' and not '-x' caused the alias list not to show anymore.

Comment: Beware that in the new "Blue Ocean" view that Jenkins gives you, these environment variables will still be visible in the UI. We got round this by writing the commands to a file (using a writefile pipeline step) and then executing the file.

Comment: @Bretc many thanks for your suggestion. That is indeed the way if you want to hide from both blue ocean and console output, most part of the answers around just mention how to hide from classic log output.

Answer (score 7):

For instances where post processing is required. I extended the original solution provided here.

For example

```
def output = printWithNoTrace("ping -c 1 $FQDN | grep PING).trim()
```

wrapper function

```
def printWithNoTrace(cmd) {
steps.sh (script: '#!/bin/sh -e\n'+ cmd,returnStdout: true)
        }
```

The shell output is returned to trim() and saved to "output"