# Jenkins podTemplate disbale default echo

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-kubernetes

I am running my jenkins in Kubernetes to create dynamic slave pod based on requirement.

And each file is uses some credentials from jenkins.

Now the problem is when I run some command in sh script:"" then that credentials are visible on log view option on UI.

as below screenshot.

[image]

My **Jenkinsfile** is looks like below

```
podTemplate(
    containers: [
        containerTemplate(name: 'helm', alwaysPullImage: true, image: 'k8s-helm:v3.4.2', command: 'cat',
            ttyEnabled: true)
    ],
    imagePullSecrets: ['registry-credentials']) {
  properties([parameters(
      [string(name: 'dockerImageTag', description: 'Docker image tag to deploy'),
       string(name: 'branchName', defaultValue: 'dev', description: 'Branch being deployed'),
       string(name: 'targetBranch', defaultValue: 'dev', description: 'Target branch against which if a PR is being raised')])])

  currentBuild.description = "branch ${params.branchName}"
  node(POD_LABEL) {

    container('helm') {
      withCredentials([[$class       : 'FileBinding',
                        credentialsId: 'sling-test-kubeconfig',
                        variable     : 'KUBECONFIG'],
                       [$class       : 'StringBinding',
                        credentialsId: 'sd-charts-github-api-token',
                        variable     : 'API_TOKEN']]) {
        stage('Add Helm repository') {
          sh script: "helm repo add stable 'https://charts.helm.sh/stable'",
              label: 'Add stable helm repo'
          sh script: 'helm repo list', label: 'List available helm repos'
        }
        withCredentials([[$class       : 'StringBinding',
                          credentialsId: 'test-env-postgres-password',
                          variable     : 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD'],
                         [$class       : 'StringBinding',
                          credentialsId: 'test-env-rabbitmq-password',
                          variable     : 'RABBITMQ_PASSWORD']]) {

          stage('Deploy') {
            echo "Deploying docker release -> myhost.com/8023/sling/scheduler:${params.dockerImageTag}"
            sh script: "scheduler charts/scheduler " +
                "--set appConfig.postgres.password=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}," +
                "image.tag=${params.dockerImageTag}," +
                "appConfig.rabbitmq.password=${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}," +
                "deployment.annotations.buildNumber=${currentBuild.number} " +
                "--wait",
                label: 'Install helm release'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This file has some credentials (i.e. RABBITMQ_PASSWORD, POSTGRES_PASSWORD etc... there are lot more then this) which I do not want to show on UI logs, basically I don't want to show entire command which is at

```
sh script: "scheduler charts/scheduler " +
                "--set appConfig.postgres.password=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}," +
                "image.tag=${params.dockerImageTag}," +
                "appConfig.rabbitmq.password=${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}," +
                "deployment.annotations.buildNumber=${currentBuild.number} " +
                "--wait",
                label: 'Install helm release'
```

I got some [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891926/how-to-disable-command-output-in-jenkins-pipeline-build-logs) but this is also not working.

Can someone please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid leaking your credentials into the output, you need to resolve them within the shell interpreter of the shell step method instead of within Jenkins Pipeline. Since `withCredentials` temporarily assigns to environment variables, this is possible by not interpolating within Groovy:

```
sh script: 'scheduler charts/scheduler ' + // literal string
           '--set appConfig.postgres.password=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD},' + // no Groovy interpolation
           "image.tag=${params.dockerImageTag}," + // Groovy interpolation
           'appConfig.rabbitmq.password=${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD},' + // no Groovy interpolation
           "deployment.annotations.buildNumber=${currentBuild.number} " +  // Groovy interpolation
           '--wait', // literal string
           label: 'Install helm release'
```

This will interpolate and concatenate the string put argument to the shell step method accurately and without exposing your credentials in the Jenkins Pipeline output.